# Order by `updated_at` and `created_at` even if they are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to sort the entries by both `updated_at` and `created_at`.

But either of them could be `NULL`.

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `entries`
ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC, `created_at` DESC, `id` DESC
```

But this will put every entry which has not been updated at the bottom of the results.

Basically I need them to be sorted by the last date available. And if there is none available to be sorted by `id`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(updated_at, created_at) DESC, id DESC
```

This orders by either the updated date (if available) or the created date (if it is not available).  Then it orders by id descending.

Comment: Tested, confirmed and accepted. This is the most simplest and gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM `entries`
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `updated_at` IS NOT NULL then `updated_at` WHEN `created_at` IS NOT NULL then `created_at` ELSE `id` END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `entries`
ORDER BY COALESCE(updated_at, created_at, id) DESC
```

This isn't necessarily *exactly* what you asked for, but it's likely getting into the direction you want.  If it's not right, can you post an example of what you want?

Comment: the types in coalesce have to be the same, so id won't work in there. Having the same quandry myself because coalesce seemed right for this, except for the type difference of id. Thoughts? Perhaps convert it?

Comment: This looks really nice, but if `COALESCE` cannot be used with different types indeed then I am not able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you want but you can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `entries`
ORDER BY IFNULL(`updated_at`,`created_at`) DESC, `id` DESC
```

If one of those dates is available, the results will be sorted by the date.
If no date is available, the result will be sorted by id.

Note: IFNULL is not necessarily available on your DBMS but you can find an equivalent.

Comment: If both `updated_at` and `created_at` for some entries are `NULL` then they will be put on top of the others and then sorted by `id`. I guess it will work with `ORDER BY IFNULL(updated_at, IFNULL(created_at, id)) DESC`