# Sort by either created_at or updated_at (whichever is more recent) Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am having what feels like a simple problem, except I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a group of records:

`@mymonkeys = @user.monkeys.all`

What I need are the 3 monkeys that have most recently been interacted with (either created or updated).

I can get the most recently created monkeys like this:
`@mymonkeys.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse!.take(3)`

And the most recently updated monkeys like this:
`@mymonkeys.sort_by(&:updated_at).reverse!.take(3)`

But is there a line of code that returns the monkeys that have most recently been either created or updated?

Thanks so much!

PS:
I saw
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501293/order-by-updated-at-and-created-at-even-if-they-are-null) which mentioned the `coalesce` keyword but I wasn't able to determine whether or not that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is there ever a situation where `created_at` is greater than `updated_at`? In other words, I believe `updated_at == created_at` when the record is first saved.

Comment: @GSP: `created_at <= updated_at` should always be the case unless the database has gone screwy (and in that case, the data should be fixed). Both of them should be NOT NULL too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&:created_at` is syntax sugar for `{ |monkey| moneky.created_at }`. Pass the block in which you do what you want.

```
@mymonkeys.sort_by { |m| [m.created_at, m.updated_at].max }.reverse!.take(3)
```

Comment: You can do this without using `reverse()` by passing an integer to the `last()` method: `}.last(3)`. I don't know for sure but am also assuming this can be done with sql/ActiveRecord using `.order()`, i.e. without having to convert everything to an array (which I believe happens with `sort_by`).

Answer (score 3):

You can (and probably should) do this in the database but COALESCE is not what you're looking for. COALESCE is used to convert NULLs to something else in SQL, you say things like:

```
coalesce(might_be_null, what_i_want_instead_of_null)
```

In your case, you should always have both `created_at` and `updated_at` so you shouldn't have to worry about NULLs.

If you want to choose the largest of several values, then you want to use [GREATEST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST); if you want the smallest, then use LEAST; any database worth using for real work should support both GREATEST and LEAST but you could fake it with a CASE if necessary. The most recent timestamp is the GREATEST so you want to sort on `greatest(created_at, update_at)`; you also want the three most recent at the top of the list so you want a descending sort (i.e. biggest first); you can send a LIMIT 3 into the database while you're at it. That gives you:

```
three_recent_monkeys = @user.monkeys.order('greatest(created_at, updated_at) desc').limit(3)
```

This is Rails so `updated_at` should always be at least `created_at` so `greatest(created_at, updated_at)` should always be `updated_at`. That means that you can simplify things and just say:

```
three_recent_monkeys = @user.monkeys.order('updated_at desc').limit(3)
```